# xvfb freezes from xvfb:10 Is this a bug?

Tags: firefox, ubuntu, xserver, xvfb

I'm using Ubuntu 13 over amazon ws EC2 and  I'm trying to get xvfb to work but I am having issues with it hanging on the line

```
Initializing build-in extension GLX
```

I believe that this is related to a bug, perhaps a incompatability with xserver?

Does anyone have any advice on where I can further look for the problem or how I can fix it